# Why does a bucket filled with water produce a metallic sound when struck with a wooden stick?

Tags: classical-mechanics, everyday-life

I observed this phenomenon: When i strike a plastic  bucket with a wooden stick, it produces a normal "plastic like" sound. But when the bucket is full of water, it produces an altogether different metallic sound. What could be the reason of this?

Comment: The speed of sound is faster in water than in air.

Comment: Does that create any difference in the perception of sound by the ears?

Comment: Have you done the experiment with a metal bucket and compared the sounds? Your characterization of the plastic bucket as metallic is simply a bias, I suspect.

Comment: What is “plastic like” sound and what is metallic sound?

Answer (score 2):

When you hit the bucket it will vibrate at its resonant frequencies (to be accurate, it initially vibrates at a wide range of frequencies, but non-resonant frequencies quickly die away leaving only resonant frequencies). A metal bucket will be stiffer than a plastic bucket and so its resonant frequencies will be higher, producing a higher pitched sound.

When you fill the plastic bucket with water then you change its resonant frequencies. If the resonant frequencies become higher (which is probable, as the water will make the bucket stiffer) then the sound will become more like a metal bucket.